# Can I have a multivalued attributes in IotAgent-UL an OrionCB?

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

My situation is as follows:

I have a device with multiple attributes. One of those attributes is called `DTC` (diagnostic trouble codes) that is intended to store a different quantity of error codes each time a meassure is sent. I mean, at a certain moment the device could send 0, 1 or more error codes.

What must I do in order to make `DTC` attribute something like a `list`?

I need to do that in `IoTAgentUL` and `Orion CB`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Orion you can use arrays to store multivalued attributes

example:

```
{
   "myAttr": {
     "type": "List",
     "value": ["a", "b", "c"]
   }
}
```

I don't know whether the UL protocol supports multivalued attributes.

Answer (score 0):

After researching a while I figured it out.

In IoTAUL is not possible.

In IoTAJson yes it's possible. The way to reach that is doing the following:

The request's body has to be as follows:

```
{
    "myAttr": ["a", "b", "c"]
}
```